# Cruise from Greece to Turkey and back to Greece - what is the "duration of intended stay"?

Tags: schengen-visas, greece, cruising

I'm taking a cruise with my wife. I'm a British citizen and she is a Chinese citizen; we live in the UK where she has permanent residence. The ship is departing from and returning to Athens, but in between it's calling at some ports in Turkey.

When applying for a Schengen visa (multiple entry as we are anyway planning to travel to Italy later the same year), when specifying the "intended date of departure from the Schengen area" (which, for multiple entries, is the date of first departure) is this the date when the ship first calls at a Turkish port, or the date when the cruise ends?

Also, related to this, when specifying the entry permit when leaving the Schengen area, is it the entry to Turkey or the entry to UK after the cruise ends?

We have contacted the cruise line, but they could not answer our questions.